# Create mongodb user from python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to create a db user from Python with pymongo. But I keep getting pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: CMD_NOT_ALLOWED: createUser error

```
client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://username:password@mycluster-mogiz.mongodb.net/admin")
db = client["testDB"]
db.command("createUser", "user", pwd="password")
```

am I missing something? Thanks.

Note: my db is on Mongo Atlas don't know if this changes anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked this problem to Atlas customer support and they gave me this answer hope it helps other people who tries the same thing. In short you cannot add user to Atlas with pymongo that is why it keeps giving error.

> Hello,
>   User management in MongoDB Atlas can only be accomplished by creating MongoDB Users in the following ways;
>   via the Web UI or 
>   with the API 
>   All MongoDB users for Atlas are associated with the admin database; i.e. their authentication database is admin. The authentication database does not determine the user’s roles.
>   Please note that the Admin database is for authentication purposes and is not meant to hold customer data.

Comment: so how do we do it with the API?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED ANSWER:

Try this.

```
client.testDB.add_user('user', 'password', roles=[{
    'role':'root',
    'db':'testDB',
}])
```

Comment: this time it gives pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: not authorized on admin to execute command

Comment: Please try out my updated answer and see if it works!

Comment: still same error. by the my db is on mongo atlas I don't know if it changes anything.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct. `add_user()` was deprecated in 3.6 and removed in 4.0. The replacement method command() is only available for M10 and larger clusters.